# How to add orderby in a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know guys this question is not that hard but I cant seem to figure out how to add orderby to my controller. Sorry guys I'm noob :(. This is my scenario. 
I have a list of tags on my view. Whenever I select a tag, a list of post will appear with the same tagname of the selected tag. My codes works fine. Only that whenever I select a tag, the list that it shows is in descending order. The latest one is on the bottom. I want it on top. :(
**CURRENTLY MY OUTPUT**
3
2
1
**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**
1
2
3

This is my controller. I can't seem to figure out how to do the logic of orderby in my browse.

```
    public ActionResult PostTags() // This is one is ok
    {
        IQueryable<Tag> tags = from tg in db.Tags
                               orderby tg.Name ascending
                               select tg;
        return View(tags);
    }

   public ActionResult Browse(string tag) // This is where I can't seem to figure out how add orderby 
    {
        var tagModel = db.Tags.Include("Posts").Single(ts => ts.Name == tag);

        return View(tagModel);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me. 
UPDATE: This is my Post tag view

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.Tag>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PostTags";
}

<h3>Tags</h3>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <ul>
            <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Browse", "Post",
                   new { Tag = item.Name }, null)
           </li>
    </ul>
}

//and this is my browse View
@model List<ProjectPAL.Models.Tag>

@foreach (var tag in Model.Posts)
{   

  <div><a href="@Href("~/Post/Details/" + tag.ID)">@tag.Title</a></div> 
   <a href="@Href("~/Post/Details/" + tag.ID + "#leavecomment")">Add a Comment</a>          
}
```

Comment: Try -db.Tags.Include("Posts").Orderby().Single(ts => ts.Name == tag)

Comment: You want to get a list of post for the tag, or a list of tag (on what basis) ?

Comment: Moby brought up a good question: `why are you trying to sort a Single`?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal it shows a red wavy line _No overload for method 'OrderBy' takes 0 arguments_ :(

Comment: @Shyju I want to get a list of post for the tag

Comment: @DaveA that's because that's the way I've done it before :(.. But I'm open for suggestions how to do it in a better way. I know mine is not a good practice.

Comment: please explain 1 thing: if youre getting back a `Single`, why do you need to sort?

Comment: The output that it shows is in descending order :(.. I just want to reverse it. To be honest I don't really understand how the term Single works, I know I'm just using it so I can't argue with you. I just a newbie and noob. :(

Comment: Single should return back 1 object. Not even List type. You shouldn't be getting multiple objects from Single. That's what confuses me so much.

Comment: @DaveA thanks for making me understand it. I'll never use single again next time when calling a list. I now working out a new way to solve it without using Single. I still have to learn a lot of things. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you want to get the collection of **Post**'s of the purticular **Tag**. Assuming you have your entities like this

```
public class Post
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { set; get; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { set; get; }
}
```

and you have overridden the `OnModelCreating` method of your DBContext class to create a third table to store your `PostId` and `TagId` (Assuming it is a many-to-many relationship)

Then you can update your action method code like below to get the Posts which has a tag same as what user passed to the action method. You can add the `OrderBy` method to the result of the `Where` method.

```
public ActionResult Browser(string tag)
{
    using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
    {
        var postsForTag = db.Posts
                           .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(o => o.Name == tag)) 
                           .OrderBy(y => y.ID).ToList();

        // TO DO : Return the above collection / appropriate view model.         

    }
}
```

**EDIT :** In your earlier comment you said,you want to show a list of Post's for the tag, so you should update your view to have it strongly typed to a collection of Post's .

```
@model List<Blog.Models.Post>
<h2>Posts</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Title</p>
}
```

Comment: I like it this way but sad to say I'm using Entity Framework.. :(

Comment: it gives me an error _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Blog.Models.Post]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Blog.Models.Tag'._ :(

Comment: looks like your view is strongly typed to Tag class. but we are passing a list of Post objects. So it should be `model List<Post>`

Comment: _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Blog.Models.Tag]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Blog.Models.Tag]'._ :( You know of all the answers here yours makes sense. I now faced another erro.

Comment: What are you passing to the view ? a list of Post or list of Tag ?

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestions. I now beginning to understand it. I'll try to work it myself. thanks for making me understand it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your navigation properties are set up, I would search the posts, rather than the way you did it:

```
var tagModel = db.Posts.Where(p => p.Tag.Name == tag).OrderBy(p => p.PostPropertyYouWantToOrder);
```

What you were doing is making the statement retrieve all tags with posts, then narrowing it down. Go for the path of least resistance.

Comment: sorry I stuck on this line _var tagModel = db.Posts.Where(p => p.Tag_ I cant use Tag. I can only use Tags and after that I cant see name on it. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you return the tagModel to the view, I suppose that you render the Posts through a foreach loop, something like this:

```
@foreach(var post in Model.Posts)
{
    //your html
}
```

If I'm right, you can do this to order the post like you want:

```
@foreach(var postin Model.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.PostID))
{
    //your html
}
```

Comment: Its a good idea but it shows a red wavy line says _No overload for method 'OrderByDescending' takes 0 arguments_

Comment: @Carl Edited, just sort by the field you need